# Is there a way to automatically close idle pgadmin processes with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, pgadmin

I am running a Node.js (Node v14.15.4) application with Sequelize (v6.6.2) as an ORM connecting to a PostgreSQL database and after several operations, i find that there is about 35 idle processes on my pgadmin dashboard, see below image for reference:
[image]

In my index file, i have setup Sequelize like below:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], {
logging: false,
pool: {
  max: 15,
  min: 0,
  acquire: 30000,
  idle: 10000,
  evict: 10000
}
```

});

is there something that i am missing here? Because i understand that evict instructs sequelize to remove any idle processes after the specified amount of time.

Comment: "idle" transactions are mostly harmless. "idle in transaction" would raise my attention.

Answer (score 1):

The connections with application name as "pgAdmin 4 - CONN-*" are used by the query tool of pgAdmin. Check if you have any open instances of query tool.